# Print check_cxx_source_runs() detailed output

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I have a find package module that utilizes `check_cxx_source_runs()` to test if package was loaded properly. However, it fails and I am not sure what causes it to.

Is there any way I can print the actual error (as one would see on terminal) from `check_cxx_source_runs()` rather than just the variable that tells success/failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error output in "*CMakeError.log*" under the build directory.